# Curl of the electrostatic field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vector-fields

In Griffith's EM text he calculates the curl for the E field of a point charge (at the origin).

He shows that the line integral of an arbitrary closed loop is zero:
$$
\oint E\cdot dl = 0
$$

and then immediately invokes Stoke's Theorem to conclude that the curl is 0. However, this step is not obvious to me. From Stoke's Theorem we know that
$$
\int (\nabla\times E)\cdot da=0.
$$

Why are we allowed to conclude that the integrand is 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In Griffith's EM text he calculates the curl for the E field of a
>   point charge (at the origin).
>
> He shows that the line integral of an arbitrary closed loop is zero:
>   $$ \oint E\cdot dl = 0 $$
>
> and then immediately invokes Stoke's Theorem to conclude that the curl
>   is 0. However, this step is not obvious to me. From Stoke's Theorem we
>   know that $$ \int (\nabla\times E)\cdot da=0. $$
>
> Why are we allowed to conclude that the integrand is 0?

It is not zero in general.

But, if (as you state) he has shown that 
$$ \oint E\cdot dl = 0 $$
for *arbitrary* closed loops,
then it is true that 
$$ \int (\nabla\times E)\cdot da=0 $$
for arbitrary areas.
Because
$$ \int (\nabla\times E)\cdot da=\oint E\cdot dl. $$

And so the integrand $\nabla\times E$ is zero in this case because the integral is zero for arbitrary areas.

Comment: It's not true that an integral being zero means that the integrand is zero, but generally if an integral is zero for ANY domain, then the integrand is zero. So I feel like your answer isn't good.

Comment: Yea yeah, I was in the process of editing my answer...

Answer (score 0):

If the closed line integral of a vector field is 0, then by the fundamental theorem for line integrals it can be expressed as a gradient of some scalar function. Substituting the gradient of this scalar function for $E$ in the second equation shows that the second integral must be 0, because the curl of a gradient is always 0.